# How do i only allow users that created a category to edit it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables `bookmarks` and `categories`. These models have a HABTM relationship.

Everything works as it should but I only want to allow `users` who created a `category` to be able to edit them. I have this set up on the `bookmarks` okay but is there a way to do it using the relationship between `bookmarks` and `categories` or do I just set it up the same way as `bookmarks`? which is having a `user_id` in the `categories` table.

Comment: Your requirement is - you want only the users who created the bookmark to edit them?

Comment: Yes, Is there a way to do this using the relationship between the bookmarks and categories or do I just create a user id column in the categories table

Comment: Please see my answer below for both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 2 join tables:

user.rb

```
has_many :categories, :through => :user_categories
```

category.rb

```
has_many :users, :through => :user_categories
has_many :bookmarks, :through => :bookmark_categories

def is_editable_by?(user)
  user.category.include? self
end
```

bookmark.rb

```
has_many :categories, :through => :bookmark_categories
has_many :users, :through => :categories
```

your_view.html.erb

```
if category.is_editable_by? current_user
  <%= link_to "edit", edit_category_path, category %>
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is

a) only the user who created the bookmark can edit them

Then we need to have a separate column `user_id` in `bookmark` model to store the creator of the bookmark and allow access similar to `category`.

b) the user who created the category can edit any bookmarks under that category, then we can just use the associated to get the users with permissions.

bookmark.rb

```
Class BookMark < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories, :through => :bookmark_categories
   has_many :users, :through => :categories
end
```

and we can just say `bookmark.users.include?(current_user)` then allow edit only if this condition satisfies.